# How can I get the field type of an inputfield displayed within a repeat tag?

Tags: visualforce, jquery, inputfield, extension

### Background

I have a Map of sObjects and a List of API field names (from Custom Settings) to dynamically control the fields that display in a table on a Visualforce page.

Here's the Apex to get all fields:

```
// get all fields from Custom Settings
Map<String, Field__c> Fields = Field__c.getAll(); 
List<String> Columns = new List<String>();
for(Field__c f : Fields.values()) { Columns.add(f.API_Name__c); }
```

A custom extension for a Visualforce page is used to retrieve the fields and an `<apex:repeat>` iterates over them. It looks something like this (I changed the code to be more generic, for this example):

```
<table class="datatable display" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <!-- ... -->
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <apex:repeat value="{!sObjectMap}" var="key">
      <tr id="{!sObjectMap[key]['Id']}">
        <apex:repeat value="{!Columns}" var="col">
          <td>
            <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(OR(col=='Name',col=='Subject'),true,false)}">
              <apex:outputlink value="/{!sObjectMap[key].Id}" target="_blank">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!sObjectMap[key][col]}" />
              </apex:outputlink>
            </apex:outputpanel>
            <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(OR(col=='Name',col=='Subject'),false,true)}">
              <apex:inputfield value="{!sObjectMap[key][col]}" showDatePicker="false" />
            </apex:outputpanel>
          </td>
        </apex:repeat>
      </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
  <tbody>
<table>
```

### Question

How can I get the type of the `<apex:inputfield>` that is being displayed when it is dynamically determined (either in an `<apex:repeat>`, `<apex:pageblocktable>`, or `<apex:datatable>`)? Ideally this type should be stored somewhere on the field so that it can be selected using jQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found a solution using the [`$ObjectType`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_objecttype.htm) global variable.

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!sObjectMap[key][col]}" 
    styleClass="type-{!$ObjectType.Custom_sObject__c.Fields[col].type}" />
```

This results in the type being added as a CSS class.

Here's how a picklist renders:

```
<select id="j_id0:j_id8:j_id15:0:j_id17:4:j_id23" 
    class="type-picklist" name="j_id0:j_id8:j_id15:0:j_id17:4:j_id23">
```

And here's a date field:

```
<input id="j_id0:j_id8:j_id15:0:j_id17:5:j_id23" class="type-date" type="text" 
    value="10/2/2013" size="12" name="j_id0:j_id8:j_id15:0:j_id17:5:j_id23">
```

This way, I can use jQuery to select all picklist fields simply by selecting all inputs with the `type-picklist` class (or dates with the `type-date` class).

```
var allPicklistInputs = $(".type-picklist");
var allDateInputs = $(".type-date");
```